# Baud Rate calculation from logic analyzer

Tags: digital-logic, uart, serial, baudrate

I am somewhat new to approaching this from this angle, been using serial coms as documented for many many years configuring everything from radios to network equipment. Familiar with what baud rate IS but not so certain on how it gets calculated. I have been doing research and it I have seen it referenced as (1/pulse width in microsecond)*(10^6) But it does not matter how *about* I get this, I always get gibberish in my terminal.

I have tried all the standard increments and figure this has to be something obscure and specific.

I know the data is there and I know it is serial, because my LA (Kingst LA2016) is reading and converting to ASCII, it is forming words and sentences, so the data IS correct.

Using a sample of a completed frame of data /8 or /9 with stop bit, or an individual bit, I am still not getting a functional baud rate.

Using this sample, can someone explain what I am getting wrong here?
IF the sample will not give the information, can you detail what I would need to look at show?

[image]

Edit:
Still working on this, and figured out KingstVis does this math for me, I see that it works it out to 575208, which is awefull close to 576000, but still no joy :/
[image]

I do not think it matters but this is wired into pin 3 RX and pin 4 GRD on a "0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC" USB-C cable. Just in case that seems like a culprit...

Comment: Zoom in closer on your logic analyzer so that you can measure the width of a single bit more accurately. [1 / (bit-width) ] is your baud rate.

Comment: Just did that and reposted. I use this serial cable sometimes several times a week, and never had an issue. I even use it from my phone sometimes. So I am hesitant to suspect cable? That gives me 114942 which is awful close to 115200, but no joy there either.

Comment: Your analyzer is giving you the measurement from one rising edge to the next, which tells you the frequency as if it's a repeating square wave - but it's not. You need the width of a single bit, from a rising edge to a falling edge (or the other way around). That looks to be about 8.6uSec. Which gives you a likely baud rate of 115200.

Comment: @Sabre Just to be clear, the logic anayzer shows correct data and baud rate can be guessed to be 115200, but where are you plugging the logic analyzer, and are you feeding that same signal into USB adapter? Is the USB adapter you have a USB-to-TTL adapter with wires or USB-to-RS232 adapter with DE9 connector? There is a **big** difference.

Comment: I'm sure it's 115200. To reduce measurement inaccuracy, I commonly count 10 bits and use that interval. -- BTW, you added some important information in comments below the first answer. Please [edit] your question and add it there. Comments are too easily overseen.

Comment: @JustMe it is like this one, different sticker on outside but same pin out/chip. https://www.amazon.com/OIKWAN-Compatible-Opengear-Aruba%EF%BC%8CJuniper-Switches/dp/B075V1RGQK/ 1-CTS, 2-DSR, 3-RXD, 4-GND, 5-GND, 6-TXD, 7-DTR, 8-RTS Logic analyzer is clipped to the same pin the leads from 3 & 4 is connected to. I have Pin 3 connected to board's TX (as indicated by the LA) and 4 to board's  (as working gin the LA). For terminal I have used minicom, screen, putty, and just opening the /dev/ttyUSB0 raw. I get data, it is all just gibberish in the console. Have tried cable and LA same time and not.

Comment: Just as a note there, the LA software identifies it as RS232 when it decodes it. I only have the TX/GRD connected because I do not want to chance sending any data until I know I have the coms correct, so 2 wire (And it appears RX is disabled at the time anyway). The pad has 4 test points, and belongs to a camera controller. Two points show continuity to ground, one swings around 3.5v (assumed/confirmed as TX) the other appears disconnected entirely (likely severed to prevent RX., but can find and fix that)

Comment: @Sabre I bet the logic analyzer can't determine if the voltage levels are RS-323 or something else. The protocol should not be called RS-232 because it's not something it defines. That's just logic level UART protocol, sometimes called asynchronous start stop protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the incorrect cable for what you are trying to do.

That's an RS-232 cable you are using.

It needs RS-232 voltage levels on input.

You are giving it a logic level signal.

The RS-232 levels are also inverted in comparison to logic levels.

So, you either need a different cable without RS-232 levels, or, you need a RS-232 transceiver board to convert your logic level signals to RS-232 levels.

Comment: Ahh, this makes some sense. Suggestions? Something like this? https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/sparkfun-electronics/DEV-09873/5318746

Comment: Asking for suggestions, what to buy and from where, are off topic. Any logic level (non-RS232) USB to UART chip device/module/cable may work for you as long as it uses the same logic voltage levels as the device you are connecting to.

Comment: 10:4 I will do some research. Thanks for the lead, they are cheap, so will just get one and try, will report back.

Comment: So ordered a 1.8v, 3.3v, 5v USB - TTL adapter, should know next week if this is purely a voltage issue, and not  BAUD rate issue. :-)

Comment: You were absolutely correct, after some research this was suspected to be a logic level issue, https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/logic-levels and a a new interface, still reports "Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC" but is adjustable  0-5 volts. This new interface reads it at 115200 like a dream set to 3.3v. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I have seen it referenced as (pulse width in microsecond / 10)*(6^10) But it does not matter how about I get this, I always get gibberish in my terminal.

Baud rate is the number symbols transferred per second. Therefore if the pulse width is longer the baud rate should be lower, not higher.

A more plausible formula is

$$ B = \frac{1}{T_s}$$

where \$B\$ is baud rate and \$T_s\$ is the symbol duration (what you call pulse width) in seconds.

The main point is the symbol duration or pulse width should be in the denominator not the numerator. The other factor in your formula (you wrote "6^10" but you probably meant \$10^6\$ is just to convert from microseconds to seconds.

In your sample the symbol period is about 10 us, so the baud rate is about 100 kbaud. The nearest common UART rate is 115.2 kbaud, so I'd start there.

Comment: You are correct I typed wrong on my phone on the way to dinner, I just got back to computer and checked, I tried (1/10)*(10^6) and came up with 100000, which result din gibberish, so I tried 115200, gibberish. so I tried 1/9.5, 1/10.5, 1/11, just in case I was slightly off. Does it have to be to the digit exact? KingstVis exports as both CSV and BIN, I tried importing into sigrok to see if I could get more precise calculations, no go. The LA2016 is collecting in 5s intervals at 200Mhz.

Comment: I do not think it matters but this is wired into pin 3 RX and pin 4 GRD on a "0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC". cable .Just in case that seems like a culprit...

Comment: @Sabre, I'm pretty sure you've got the baud rate correct at 115.2 kbaud. Try looking at other settings like start/stop bits, parity bits, etc.

Comment: Any way to glean that or trial and error? The analyzer decodes the data, so I assume it is determining this somehow?

Comment: @Sabre, your trace looks to me like 1 start bit, no parity. But I don't work with serial data much.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you, this actually did correct/confirm/answer my original question, the other solved my problem (And likely will for others finding this and having the same issue) If I could split the answer acceptance I would :-)